# TalbeView cell showing null value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I have created a custom table for the `rootViewController` of a split view application so that the selected row expands and shows as a sub-table (showing main menu and sub menu ). The first row of the sub-table should show the particular main menu item of the sub-table.I'm fetching the main menu items from another class.

The problem is that the first row for the sub table is showing blank for me.Using NSLog, I checked the value of variable just before assigning it to the cell and even after assigning the value to the cell, i checked the text value in the cell using `cell.textLabel.text`. I'm getting the value in the console every time, but the row is still blank!!!

Row is showing the value if I'm hard coding it with any value!!!

Note:`TableView` is showing values for remaining rows.

Anybody can help me?? Thanks in advance...and sorry for my poor English..

EDIT: In the `rootViewController`:

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    tableView.separatorColor=[UIColor grayColor];

    if (sectionopen[indexPath.row]) {
        accordianTable *cell1;
        cell1=(accordianTable *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell1"];

        if (cell1 == nil) {
            cell1 = [[[accordianTable alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"cell1"] autorelease];
        }

        cell1.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        return cell1;
    } else {
    //tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    // Dequeue or create a cell of the appropriate type.
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    }
    // Configure the cell.
    cell.textLabel.text=[UIAppDelegate.mainMenu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
    }    
}

(void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    accordianTable *acc = [[accordianTable alloc]init];
    acc.titl=[UIAppDelegate.mainMenu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [acc.subTable reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    ///turn them all off
    sectionopen[0]=NO;
    sectionopen[1]=NO;
    sectionopen[2]=NO;
    sectionopen[3]=NO;

    ///open this one
    sectionopen[indexPath.row]=YES;

    ///animate the opening and expand the row
    [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    UIViewController  *localdetailViewController = nil;
}
```

In the custom cell class (accordianTable):

```
(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Number of rows is the number of time zones in the region for the specified section.
    return [UIAppDelegate.subMenu count]+1;//including title and sub menu
}

(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    switch (indexPath.row)
    {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"text is   >>  %@",titl);
            cell.textLabel.text=titl;
            NSLog(@"text is   >>  %@",cell.textLabel.text);
            cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
            cell.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
            cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            break;            
        default:
            int Row=indexPath.row;
            Row--;
            cell.textLabel.text=[UIAppDelegate.subMenu objectAtIndex:Row];
            cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
            cell.textLabel.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
            cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            break;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: can you add a bit of your code to the question? It would be very helpful to those who want to answer your question.

Comment: @Nithin: Thank you for your reply.I have edited the question with a bit of codes.